# How do I compile my Hibernate generated POJO?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm not sure how to proceed.  I have my Hibernate myclass.java, but I need the class.  Build and Clean are grayed out.  I have a web application I'm trying to add this to (inherited so learning), but I need it to be a .class.

Eclipse is set to Build Automatically but there is no class in my project folder.

What do I do to get the compiled version (.class)?

There is no Main class so I can't use the java command line to compile it.

Comment: the .class file is in build.. or you can compile in console

Comment: There's nothing there, only the configuration files and the .java file.  I can't use the command line because there is no Main method.

Comment: the .java is in source.. in build/classes

Comment: if it's a web application check WEB-INF/classes for the .class file

Comment: Do you have to have  main to compile?